# Numpy, how to add column names to Numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

this probably has some duplicate threads but I honestly couldn't find a suitable solution. Pandas will be an easy solution but in the project I am working on will not include pandas as a dependency.

I am trying to add column names to a Numpy array, basically turning it into structured array even though the data type are all the same.

I tried:

```
signal = np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]])
col_names = ('left','right','center')
signal = np.array(signal, dtype = [(n, 'int16') for n in col_names])
```

but this returns:

```
array([[(1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2), (3, 3, 3)],
       [(1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2), (3, 3, 3)],
       [(1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2), (3, 3, 3)]],
      dtype=[('left', '<i2'), ('right', '<i2'), ('center', '<i2')])
```

Basically, I have a Numpy array representing a multi-channel signal. I want to be able to subset the channels using column names:

```
signal['left'] == signal[:,0] # True
signal[['left','center']] == signal[:,[0,2]] # True
```

I also saw a post someone advised against using structured array. Is there a potential downside to it? Say it makes the array slower to access?

Answer (score 1):

The correct data input form for a structured array is a list of tuples:

```
In [71]: signal = [(1,2,3),(2,3,1),(3,2,1)] 
    ...: col_names = ('left','right','center') 
    ...: signal = np.array(signal, dtype = [(n, 'int16') for n in col_names])   
In [72]:                                                                        
In [72]: signal                                                                 
Out[72]: 
array([(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 1), (3, 2, 1)],
      dtype=[('left', '<i2'), ('right', '<i2'), ('center', '<i2')])
```

`1.16` has added a couple of functions that make it easier to convert to and from structured arrays:

```
In [73]: import numpy.lib.recfunctions as rfn                                   
In [74]: signal = np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]])                           
In [75]: dt = np.dtype([(n, 'int16') for n in col_names])                       
In [76]: dt                                                                     
Out[76]: dtype([('left', '<i2'), ('right', '<i2'), ('center', '<i2')])
In [77]: rfn.unstructured_to_structured(signal, dt)                             
Out[77]: 
array([(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3)],
      dtype=[('left', '<i2'), ('right', '<i2'), ('center', '<i2')])
```

Applying this `dt` to `signal` has a problem:

```
In [82]: signal.view(dt)                                                        
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-82-f0fa01ce8128> in <module>
----> 1 signal.view(dt)

ValueError: When changing to a smaller dtype, its size must be a divisor of the size of original dtype
```

We can get around that by first converting `signal` to a compatible dtype:

```
In [83]: signal.astype('i2').view(dt)                                           
Out[83]: 
array([[(1, 2, 3)],
       [(1, 2, 3)],
       [(1, 2, 3)]],
      dtype=[('left', '<i2'), ('right', '<i2'), ('center', '<i2')])
```

But note that `Out[83]` shape is (3,1).  The other arrays were shape (3,). `view` has always had this shape problem when converting to/from structured arrays.  That's part of why the newer functions are easier to use.

Comment: This does create a new structure array. But now I can no longer interchange the use of signal['left'] and signal[:,0]. Is there any way to achieve both?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the correct results by taking a view

```
>>> signal.view(dtype=[(n, signal.dtype) for n in col_names])

array([[(1, 2, 3)],
   [(1, 2, 3)],
   [(1, 2, 3)]],
  dtype=[('left', '<i8'), ('right', '<i8'), ('center', '<i8')])
```

As far as performance goes, it's not something to worry about.  Structured arrays are `ndarrays`, you just get the added benefit of having more complex datatypes.  On the other hand, record arrays are structured arrays that allow looking up field names as object attributes - that introduces some overhead to attribute lookups, but it's still generally quite minimal overhead compared to computations on the data.

Comment: Shape changes with `view`.

Comment: hi, although doing so does create a structured array, np.array_equal(a['left'], a[:,0]) is now false. because a is now only 1 column